# how to post an ajax call and C# to recognize the object

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

The following code posts using ajax successfully although I'm not sure how the server side ActionResult in MVC can make sense of the object being sent.  any ideas?  The object that needs to be posted from jquery is an object with several properties.
Thanks

```
           var url = 'abc';
           //val: { several properties, forename, surname, postcode

           jr.ajax.loadJson(url, val,
               true,
               function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               }, 
               true, 'post', val);
           });


// controller

public ActionResult Show()
{
        var list = Request.Form[0];  // can see the values in here
}


// I want the posted value to be this object

public class Test
{
    public string forename { get; set; }        
    public string surname { get; set; }        
    public string postcode { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When posting a json object you can simply add the type as a method parameter and the Object Binder will convert it

```
public ActionResult Show(Test test)
    {
         [...]
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to post your object to an action which expects an object parameter with similar properties. I am not quite sure what `loadJSON` does (I assume it's a plugin you are using?), however, when posting data you can use the standard `$.ajax` method, or `$.post` for a more simple API e.g.

**Server-side**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    ...
}

[AjaxOnly]
public ActionResult Show(MyModel model)
{
    // use model
}
```

**Client-side**

```
var obj = { Property1: 'value1', Property2: 'value2' };
$.post(url, obj, function(response) {
    alert('post successful!');  
});
```

When your data reaches the server, MVC attempts to bind the client-side object to the expected server-side type using a name/value pair approach. In otherwords, as long as the object you are passing from the client has properties with the **exact** same name & a valid value for that particular property type, it will successfully map across.